# Output array of data to an excel table using VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

So I have this array string of data:

> {"202101":8,"202102":null,"202103":null,"202104":null,"202105":null,"202106":null,"202107":null,"202108":null,"202109":null,"202110":null,"202111":null,"202112":null,"202201":null,"202202":null,"202203":null,"202204":null,"202205":null,"202206":null,"202207":null,"202208":null,"202209":null,"202210":null,"202211":null,"202212":null,"202301":null,"202302":null,"202303":null,"202304":null,"rdID":"0003600023OBK00002_ARL","Product
> Code":"0003600023OBK00002","Suffixes":"0003600023OBK00002"},
>
> {"202101":null,"202102":null,"202103":null,"202104":null,"202105":null,"202106":null,"202107":null,"202108":null,"202109":null,"202110":null,"202111":null,"202112":null,"202201":null,"202202":null,"202203":null,"202204":null,"202205":null,"202206":null,"202207":null,"202208":null,"202209":null,"202210":null,"202211":null,"202212":null,"202301":null,"202302":null,"202303":null,"202304":null,"rdID":"0003600023OBK00002_CO","Product
> Code":"0003600023OBK00002","Suffixes":"0003600023OBK00002:}

and I want to output it into a sheet as a table where the first value is the column name and the second value is the row value

so it would look something like this:

[image]

the values may not be the same, but the gist is it would put the values in a table like so.

The number of array values may also be dynamic.

Does anyone know how to do this in VBA? thank you very much.

Comment: Use `Split()` to split the string into parts from which it will be easier to extract the information - then do Loops - for Each key value pair: find the key in your sheet and put the value into the according column

Comment: That text looks like JSON, so the typical suggestion here for dealing with that would be to use this: https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON

Answer (score 1):

Import the *JsonConverter.bas* file from here - https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON into your workbook, and add a VBA project reference to the *Microsoft Scripting runtime* library.

```vb
Sub tester()
    Dim json, objJson, obj, k, wsOut As Worksheet, m, rw As Range
    
    Set wsOut = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Output")
    Set rw = wsOut.Rows(2)
    'adding [] so we get a Collection as the output
    json = "[" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("input").Range("A1").Value & "]"
    
    Set objJson = JsonConverter.ParseJson(json)
    
    For Each obj In objJson     'loop over the collection
        For Each k In obj       'obj=scripting dictionary 
            m = Application.Match(k, wsOut.Rows(1), 0) 'see if the header exists
            If IsError(m) Then  'error if no matching header
                With wsOut.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)
                    m = IIf(.Value = "", .Column, .Column + 1)
                End With
                wsOut.Cells(1, m).Value = k 'add the header
            End If
            rw.Cells(m).Value = obj(k)      'populate the value
        Next k
        Set rw = rw.Offset(1)               'next output row
    Next obj

End Sub
```